# Python C API sys.getsizeof()

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I'm trying to call a method getsizeof from a C library for Python.
Here's my code:

```
//Returns in bytes the size of obj in memory
//sys.getsizeof(obj)
size_t getSizeOf(PyObject* obj){ //obj could be dict or list
    Py_INCREF(obj);

    PyObject* sys = PyModule_New("sys"); //import sys

    PyObject* string = Py_BuildValue("s", "getsizeof");

    PyObject* res = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(sys, string, obj, NULL); //res = sys.getsizeof(obj)
    Py_DECREF(sys);
    Py_DECREF(string);

    long tmp = PyLong_AsLong(res);
    Py_DECREF(res);

    Py_DECREF(obj);
    return (size_t)tmp;
}
```

And this code gives me a segfault. No clue why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming `PyObject* obj` is not null, why would you need to `Py_INCREF(obj)` it?

Comment: From what I've read it's simply good practice

Comment: Assuming you don't really need to do that (other than some bloke on the internet saying it's "good practice"), you can remove that and its corresponding Py_DECREF from your code and have one less thing to troubleshoot.

Comment: The other thing I would try first is doing all of your other Py_DECREFS right before you return.  That way there's no chance of losing a reference until you're sure you no longer need it.

Comment: There also might be a "correct" order for the decrefs.  I would Py_DECREF `res` first, then `string`, then `sys`, in that order.

Comment: Why is that the correct order for decrefs? Isn't decref simply sort of like free()? As in the moment i don't need it it can free it?

Comment: i have a feeling if you try to pinpoint which line gives you the segfault you'll find where and what goes wrong... but one thing that is wrong is the call to `PyModule_New` since it creates a new module instead of finding the existing one.  the function you want is `PyImport_AddModule`

Comment: OOOH ok that fixed it thanks. It was segfaulting on PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs and changing PyModule_New to what you suggested fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PyImport_ImportModule` to import a module.  Also using `PyObject_CallMethod` simplifies the call.  Incrementing the incoming `obj` is not needed.

```py
#include <Python.h>

__declspec(dllexport)  // For Windows
size_t getSizeOf(PyObject* obj) {
    PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject* res = PyObject_CallMethod(sys, "getsizeof", "O", obj);
    Py_DECREF(sys);
    long tmp = PyLong_AsLong(res);
    Py_DECREF(res);
    return (size_t)tmp;
}
```

Calling method from Python:

```py
>>> import ctypes as ct
>>> dll = ct.PyDLL('./test')
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> dll.getSizeOf.argtypes = ct.py_object,
>>> dll.getSizeOf.restype = ct.c_size_t
>>> dll.getSizeOf(x)
88
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(x) # to verify
88
```

Comment: I was looking at this myself, and was going to use `PyObject_GetAttrString` followed by `PyObject_CallOneArg`. I like that you could skip that attribute lookup call by using `PyObject_CallMethod` directly once you have the module. Seems simpler +1

Comment: Is this going to cause a potential segfault by not checking if `res == NULL` before doing the `PyLong_AsLong` or `Py_DECREF` calls? I guess for a function like `getsizeof` it's very unlikely to fail, but what would be the best way to error handle here?

Comment: Yes, error checking is left as an exercise.  Check for NULL and handle accordingly.  You should also look into installing debug Python (python_d.exe) and using its reference counting checks (`-X showrefcount`) to make sure the reference counting is correct.  I did and it is.